# I am populating a number of Selects in an Angular app, one of them is showing two elements in each dropdown item

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, drop-down-menu

Note the image, it's not duplicate elements in the list, but for each row in the dropdown, two of the same value.  It's working fine, only returning one value, but it's annoying.  There are 10 other dropdowns on the same form and they are all working fine.  I've changed it from a list of text strings to a list of objects to see if that changed the behavior, but no change.  I feel like I am missing something.  The list object only contains one element for each row.  Strange, but probably simple . . . I hope.

```
    <td class="tdMultiEdit">
        <input ng-change="activeCheckBoxes.feature = true" type="text" name="featureValue" id="inputFeature" list="featureList" data-ng-model="values.featureValue" autocomplete="off">
        <datalist id="featureList">
            <option data-ng-repeat="object in featureProcessText">{{object.name}}</option>
        </datalist>
    </td>
```

[image]

Comment: hmm, I have a feeling whatever `datalist` is is showing it that way. I don't think it's two elements, looks like some sort of option label. What is `datalist`?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, Ronnie.  I first assumed something like that, but I have 10 other lists that use the identical code, they are all fine.  'datalist' is an HTML element for a predefined list of values, but when associated with a text input box, it also allows other entries, sort of a JavaComboBox.

Comment: Is datalist open source or did you make it? Just wanted to see if it had some documentation..or can you make a fiddle showing this behavior?

Comment: You can check here: (http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_datalist.asp).  It's not one I did up, it's pretty common with HTML5

Comment: oh..not sure how I haven't heard of a `datalist` yet! I thought it was directive. Can you make a fiddle showing this behavior?

Comment: Try adding 'track by' to the ngRepeat you can read more here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

Comment: I tried a quick one, but wouldn't you know it . . . it worked fine and a cut and pasted from my code.  I'll try JSFiddle again tonight and see if I can make it happen or at least figure out what's going on.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Ulmer, tried it after I changed the list from straight text to objects.  No change.  Still looks like a list with labels, but can't figure out why it's like that -- especially since the other 10 aren't doing it.

Comment: Found a work around, but I would still like to know what causes my problem.  The work around is to add a `label="option.name"` and then it only displays for one item, it's bold, but that's explainable rather than the annoying duplicate

Answer (score 0):

Ted kindly check this. I have reused your code with sample data

```
<input ng-change="activeCheckBoxes.feature = true" type="text" name="featureValue" id="inputFeature" list="featureList" data-ng-model="values.featureValue" autocomplete="off">
    <datalist id="featureList">
        <option data-ng-repeat="object in featureProcessText">{{object.name}}</option>
    </datalist>
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/FWkzndEhLrUAeOMzAwfZ?p=preview

Comment: Thanks Shamila.  Your code sorta shows my problem.  a total of 12 dropdowns on the form, coded like your Plunker.  11 of them working fine, the 12th shows the double line in each element.  The work around I found did the job for the 12, just haven't figured out what's different.  I tried to build my own plunker using my actual data and wouldn't you know it, it worked fine.  Headscratcher for sure, but I had to move past it.  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Ted...Great job